# Issue with login and registration in angular?

Tags: angular

angular version:

Angular CLI: 9.0.0-rc.7

Angular: 9.0.0-rc.7

I'm working with login but get an error:

browser console error:

formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
```

login.component.html

```
 <div class="card-body">
        <form [formGroup]="logincreteform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
              <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="username" required>
              </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password" required>
             </div>

             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Login</button>
      </form>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormsModule, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

export class LoginComponent   {

    logincreteform : FormGroup;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    ngoninit() {
        this.logincreteform = new FormGroup({
            username: new FormControl(),
            password: new FormControl()
        });
    }

   onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.logincreteform);
        let username;
        let password ;
        if (username == 'abc' && password == '123') {
            this.router.navigate(['/register']);
        }
        else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './views/register/register.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [

   ReactiveFormsModule,

  declarations: [
      LoginComponent,
      RegisterComponent
  ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and when I uncomment register page code:

then also give an error:

```
compiler.js:2531 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for ControlContainer ("
          <div class="card mx-4">
            <div class="card-body p-4">
              [ERROR ->]<form>
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <p class="text-muted">Create your account<"): ng:///AppModule/RegisterComponent.html@7:14
```

register.component.html

```
          <div class="card-body p-4">
              <form>
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <p class="text-muted">Create your account</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="username" required>
                </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                         <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="email" required>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                     <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password" required>
               </div>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Create Account</button>
         </div>
```

register.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent {

  constructor() { }

}
```

I want the simple login to enter username(abc) and password(123) then redirecting to the registration page?? what I m doing wrong?help.

Comment: I see you created a form control for username and password in login.component.ts and you didn't pass any arguments. Form control objects need at least the initial value for the field. try to put an empty quote in the statement. see https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: for your register page code, you need to map the form to a form group object before you set the formControlName for the fields in the form.

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan ```username: new FormControl('abc'),
            password: new FormControl('122')``` still give an error.

Comment: what exactly is your error?

Comment: send the console exception.

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan now register page uncomment code and not give any error of register page related but login page related give an error: (browser) ```LoginComponent.html:9 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>
```

Comment: for that HTML code what is the component.ts code?

Comment: you set the [formGroup]="myGroup" but you didn't create any myGroup instance in the component file. thats the problem. Do repeat the logincreteform form in constructor to the myGroup variable

Comment: copy and paste this in your ngOninit():
this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
            username: new firstName('')
        });

Comment: do paste the above code in ngOninit() and create a variable myGroup : FormGroup in the login component class

Comment: also, your onSubmit() method needs some changes.

Comment: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Comment: still same error?

Comment: did you create the private myGroup : FormGroup; in class and put the code i gave in the ngOnInit(). then please update your question with new code.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing formGroup in the register component. You need to add it in form tag the same as you did it in login component.

register.component.html

```
<div class="card-body p-4">
 <form [formGroup]="registerform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()>
   <h1>Register</h1>
   <p class="text-muted">Create your account</p>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="username" required>
                </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                         <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="email" required>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                     <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password" required>
               </div>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Create Account</button>
         </div>
```

you need add formGroup in you component.ts file as well.

```
`import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent {
registerform : FormGroup;
  constructor() { }

}`
```

Comment: an update to above answer, the form group must be instantiated in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

now my issue is Solved.

```
login.component.cs

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent  {

    login: FormGroup;

    constructor(private frmbuilder: FormBuilder, public router:Router) {

        this.login = this.frmbuilder.group({
            username: [''],
            password: ['']

        });
    }

 onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.login);
        let username = this.login.get('username').value;
        let password = this.login.get('password').value;
        if (username == 'abc' && password == '123') {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);     //navigate when your criteria match then redirect dashboard page otherwise give an error.(Navigation)
        }
        else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }

Do Not Forget this line in Html page

 <form [formGroup]="login" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```